# High Order Functions - How?

Tags: javascript

im pretty new at javascript and since i have no one else to ask my questions i resorted to all of you.

Im trying to create a higher-order function resorting to the forEach method on an array that comes in the form of email:password and im trying to use the split method to remove the ':' between each string of the array.

I leave my code here so you can answer me if im on the right track and what can be improved.

The array:

```js
var accounts = [
  'qewsa@mail.com:zbadaddxrl',
  'djahj@mail.com:znfdadgre', 
  'hermn@mail.com:fbppadre', 
  'erek@mail.com:trbedsastr', 
  'reey@mail.com:zvpurdsyyr', 
  'laled@mail.com:puasdsrrfr'
];
```

The code:

```js
accounts.forEach(function(entry) {
    var part = entry.split(":");
    var username = part[0];
    var password = part[1];
})
```

Comment: What's the question? Are you having problems with your code?

Comment: your foreach doesnt return anything or update the original array. seems like you should be using `map` instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know exactly why you need, but to improve your script, you can do something like:

```js
const accounts = [ 
  'qewsa@mail.com:zbadaddxrl',
  'djahj@mail.com:znfdadgre', 
  'hermn@mail.com:fbppadre', 
  'erek@mail.com:trbedsastr', 
  'reey@mail.com:zvpurdsyyr', 
  'laled@mail.com:puasdsrrfr' 
] 

// mailAndPassword will be an array of object with the structure {username: string, password: string}

const mailAndPassword = accounts.map((entry) => {
    // Here I use destructuring to get the first and second item from the split method
    const [username, password] = entry.split(":");
    // Here I return a object with the username and password
    return {username, password}
})

console.log(mailAndPassword)
```

Comment: How does this improve anything? (not the downvoter). It adds functionality the OP didn't request, I suppose.

Comment: It add ES6 features and do something with the username and password, in the snippet of OP, the username and password only is overwritten locally without any final result. Another thing is show an example of a thing that OP can do with the snippet it provide.

Comment: Thank you Oscar, it sure helped a lot!
Like i said i don't know anyone that is interested in programing so having people with experience giving sugestions or new ways i don't know is awesome

Comment: it improves it by using map instead of foreach, that alone basically solves the problem as I see it. returning it as an object instead of a string I agree is not the functionality that was asked for, but this is more funtional than OP's original code